# SQL query for database find the nr of students

Tags: sql, database

I am a beginner in databases and I have the following: I need to show the courses which have the biggest number of non-correct pupils (so those who have not brought the book yet and those who brought them later than date_to_return)

1. TABLE **COURSES**: course_code,course_name.
2. TABLE **pupils_on_courses**: pupil_id, course_code.
3. TABLE **pupils**: pupil_id
4. TABLE **books_out_on_loan**: pupil_id, isbn, date_borrowed, date_to_return_date_returned

I tried to find the number of non-correct students for each section, but now I have stuck to finding the max.

I think that the mistake is at the condition that I have for counting `date_returned` & `date_to_return`

```
select 
    c.course_code, c.course_name, count (bb.pupil_id) 
from 
    courses c 
inner join 
    pupils_on_courses ps on c.course_code = ps.course_code
inner join 
    pupils p on p.pupil_id = ps.pupil_id
inner join 
    books_out_on_loan bb on p.pupil_id = bb.pupil_id
group by 
    c.course_code, c.course_name
having 
    count (bb.pupil_id) = (select max(count(*))
                           from pupil p 
                           inner join books_out_loan bb on p.pupil_id = bb.pupil_id
                           where bb.date_returned is null 
                              or bb.date_returned > date_to_return
                           group by c.course_code, c.course_name)
```

I would appreciate the help

**EDIT:** 
Some sample data would be :
[image]

Comment: The JOIN between `pupils` and `books_out_on_loan` should be a LEFT JOIN, no?

Comment: I also tried left join... still the same result @Shiva

Comment: If you post some sample schema and data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ someone might be able to help...

Comment: No need for course name in the subquery.

Comment: You can't nest aggregate functions either.

Comment: Can you use `>= all` for the subquery?

Comment: Pupils table is unnecessary for this query.

Comment: You don't want to correlate the subquery. Right now you're grouping on static correlated values from c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    c.course_code, min(c.course_name) course_name,
    count(distinct pc.pupil_id) as max_pupil_cnt
from 
    courses c inner join pupils_on_courses pc
        on ps.course_code = c.course_code
    inner join books_out_on_loan b
        on b.pupil_id = pc.pupil_id
where b.date_returned is null or b.date_returned > b.date_to_return
group by c.course_code
having count (distinct pc.pupil_id) >= all (
    select count(distinct pc2.pupil_id)
    from pupils_on_courses pc2 inner join books_out_loan b2. 
        on b2.pupil_id = pc2.pupil_id
    where b2.date_returned is null or b2.date_returned > b2.date_to_return
    group by pc2.course_code
);
```

There are modern ways to do this without the repitition of logic. My guess is that you need to stick with basic stuff since this looks like homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you post sample data, it makes it much easier for us to help.

This might work for you, if what you want is to count the number of students and not the number of unbought books or late returns:

```
select 
    c.course_code, c.course_name, 
    count (distinct case when bb.date_returned is null or bb.date_returned > date_to_return
      then p.pupil_id else null end) as NoncorrectStudents
from 
    courses c 
inner join 
    pupils_on_courses ps on c.course_code = ps.course_code
inner join 
    pupils p on p.pupil_id = ps.pupil_id
left join 
    books_out_on_loan bb on p.pupil_id = bb.pupil_id
group by 
    c.course_code, c.course_name
```

Once you have this, you should be able to sort by number of non-correct students.  Please post data when you get the chance so it can be verified.

Comment: thank you @JJ32 i just edited some sample data above

Comment: I didn't realize this was Oracle.  In future, please use tags appropriately (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines).

I will steal @LukStorms idea above, since Oracle allows you to use window functions you can use Rank() to get the topmost result of course(s) with noncorrect-students.  In either case, the count(distinct) of pupils should get you in the right ballpark (I can't test since I'm not an Oracle user).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably filter on the 'non-correct' already in the `WHERE` clause.

Then it wouldn't return those that have only 'correct'.
But since you only want those with maximum 'non-correct' that should be fair enough.

And you might also need to select only those that had to return before the current date.

```
SELECT c.course_code, c.course_name
, COUNT(DISTINCT bb.pupil_id) AS non_correct_pupils
FROM books_out_on_loan bb 
INNER JOIN pupils_on_courses ps 
  ON ps.pupil_id = bb.pupil_id
INNER JOIN courses c 
  ON c.course_code = ps.course_code
WHERE bb.date_to_return < CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE)
AND (bb.date_returned IS NULL OR bb.date_returned > bb.date_to_return)
GROUP BY c.course_code, c.course_name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT bb.pupil_id) DESC
```

The DISTINCT is used to count only the unique pupil_id's.

To get the top ranked, try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT c.course_code, c.course_name
, COUNT(DISTINCT bb.pupil_id) AS non_correct_pupils
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT bb.pupil_id) DESC) AS Rnk
FROM books_out_on_loan bb 
INNER JOIN pupils_on_courses ps 
  ON ps.pupil_id = bb.pupil_id
INNER JOIN courses c 
  ON c.course_code = ps.course_code
WHERE bb.date_to_return < CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE)
AND (bb.date_returned IS NULL OR bb.date_returned > bb.date_to_return)
GROUP BY c.course_code, c.course_name
)
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Comment: yes, i have done this at the middle of the work, but i want to display the maximum of them, and what i mean is that there can be for example 3 sections with non correct students, but only one of the sections has the biggest nr. and I want to output that, without considering the others. Or even if two sections can have the same nr of noncorrect students, but as long as is the biggest of others, that should be the output. Can this be done with max? How? @LukStorms

Comment: Not sure what mean by sections. And you didn't tag the type of database/version you use.  But to get the top ranked, then one way is to calculate a `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT bb.pupil_id) DESC) AS Rnk`.  Wrap the query in a sub-query. Then select those with Rnk = 1.

Comment: i am using sql developer @LukStorms

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer? That's a tool, not a DBMS.  But Oracle also has the [windows functions](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/).  So give it a try with DENSE_RANK.

Comment: as i said... I'm a beginner